# Add unknown sized list of instance types and weight capacities to Auto Scaling group in AWS CF template(YAML)

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

We have an AWS Cloud Formation stack template, which creates an AutoScaling group based on Instance types and weight capacity received in the input. For different types of stack profiles number of instance types in the input differ,Error is returned if input list is smaller or larger than the mapping in CF template.
How to map an unknown sized comma-delimited list of instance types to AutoScaling Instance Type parameter(type: string)

```
Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    DependsOn:
      - SharedInfraStack
      - NodeManagerSnsTopic
    Properties:
      MixedInstancesPolicy:
        InstancesDistribution:
          OnDemandAllocationStrategy: prioritized
          OnDemandBaseCapacity: !Ref NodesPerZone
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateSpecification:
            LaunchTemplateId: !Ref MyTemplate
            Version: !GetAtt MyTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
          Overrides:
            - InstanceType: !Select [ 0, !Ref StaticDnodeVmType ]
              WeightedCapacity: !Select [ 0, !Ref StaticDnodeWeightedCapacity ]
            - InstanceType: !Select [ 1, !Ref StaticDnodeVmType ]
              WeightedCapacity: !Select [ 1, !Ref StaticDnodeWeightedCapacity ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't do this** in plain CFN. There are no loops in CFN you could use to create your instance types dynamically.

You have basically **three choices**:

1. Develop and use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to create your AutoScalingGroup.
2. Develop and use [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to dynamically generate template with correct number of instance types.
3. Don't use CFN. There are other IaC tools which have loops and could do what you want, e.g. terraform.